# How to create chatting app using swift

Tags: ios, node.js, sockets, swift2, chat

Hi am working in a app which need to send a message from one to one so that am following a example https://www.appcoda.com/socket-io-chat-app/ which works fine but this code successfully working on simulator.But when I tried to run it on iPhone device, no connection is made and i know that this app will not work unless connected to the same network as your Mac and having the Socket.IO server running on the Mac. 192.168.X.X addresses are local network addresses.Now i want my app to work all over,So help me to go this process else refer some other well working example but i don't want to use firebase

Comment: You need to communicate with Backend team, they will help you in this part. Few settings need to manage from both the end.

Comment: what are that few settings??

Comment: settings like domain name, port no., methods from which need to manage the chatting etc

Comment: is there any other examples for chat app??

Comment: Bro, currently unavailable, I need to search for this.......

Comment: can i use JSQMessagesViewController??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand what means"to work all over", but if you want to make your app visible outside the local network you have to either rent a vps with public IP or but public IP for your Mac. In the second case ask your product how to do this.

To improve you should to buy domain name (for instance, mywonderchat.com) and certificate to create secure connection instead of non-secure.

In order to find some useful URLs read this https://github.com/matteocrippa/awesome-swift/blob/master/README.md#chat

Comment: my app works only on registered IP..i want to run this app on all devices..thats what am mentioning "to work all over"

Comment: @user3549189 why do you think that it doesn't work on the other devices? Read my updated post too

Comment: is there any other options to work with chatting using mobile database

Answer (score 0):

You can use Twilio's chat SDK in Swift to create your application. It's one of the best chat API I have come across. Here, you will be focusing mainly on your application's logic and UI while other boilerplate code will already be managed by them.